# Integral involving $\sec(x^4)$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

$$\int (18x^3)((\sec(x^4))^4 \,dx$$

I did this:

$$(18/4)(\int(4x^3)(\sec (x^4))^2 (\sec (x^4))^2)\, dx$$

From here I have no idea where to go. I'm not sure if I should substitute. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Use a U-substitution to get rid of the $x^4$ inside of your secant function

Comment: The thing to notice is that $x^3$ outside is (almost) the derivative of $x^4$.  If that $x^3$ were not there, you would be sunk.

Comment: if $u'(x) = (4x^3)(\sec(x^4))^2$, then what is $u(x)$? Hint: think chain rule.

Answer (score 3):

why not change variable? using $x^4 = u. du = 4x^3 dx$ we can transform $$ \int 18 x^3 (\sec x^4)^4 \, dx= \frac92\int \sec^4 u \, du =  \frac92 J$$

$\begin{align} J = \int \sec^2 u \,d \tan u 
&= \sec^2u \tan u - 2\int \tan u \sec u \sec u \tan u \, du\\
&= \sec^2u \tan u - 2\int \sec^2 u(\sec^2 u - 1) \, du\\
&= \sec^2u \tan u - 2J + 2\int \sec^2 u) \, du\\
&= \sec^2u \tan u - 2J + 2\tan u\\
\end{align}$

therefore $$ J = \frac13\left( \sec^2u \tan u + 2 \tan u\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=x^4$, we have

$\int18x^3\sec(x^4)^4dx=\frac{18}{4}\int\sec^4udu$

$=\int \sec^2 ud\tan u$

$=\int (\tan^2u+1)d\tan u$

Let $v=\tan u$, we get

$\int (v^2+1)dv=\frac{1}{3}v^3+v+C.$

Plugging back in the expressions of u and v you'll get $\frac{1}{3}\tan(x^4)^3+\tan(x^4)+C$ as your final answer.